# I created an event in 1 viewmodel and want another to subscribe to it, how do I find it? WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, viewmodel

As the title states... how can I find a different viewmodel....

My first guess would be to search for the usercontrol it's bying used by and go through that... but it seems a lot of work for something that must be easy to find....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Make use of **Messenger Class.**

When you want to execute the method present in one *Viewmodel* in Other *ViewModel*.. You can simply send a message to the *ViewModel*(which holds the event you want to execute) from the *ViewModel*(From which you want to acess) and can execute that event.

Register the **Message** in the *Constructor* of class in which the event is declared.
Send the **Message** from the *viewmodel*(in which you want to access) at the point you want to use that event.

Comment: is this messenger class based on a different project? http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/

Comment: NO..It comes with MVVM Light Toolkit...Which framework are you Using??

Comment: I don't have a framework, it's not my project yet.... Will be in a month, where I'll be able to use a framework to make life easier, All I can do now is add functionality in a limited format.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a general messaging mechanism that allows you to communicate between VM's - see MVVM Light for example

Answer (score 0):

How do the two view models relate? Is one a parent of the other? In this best case scenario, you can just expose an event or delegate in one that the other subscribes to.

Similarly, if they have a common parent, this could be done in the parent view model.

If there is no relation, how about putting all common functionality into a base view model class. If the event or delegate is exposed in the base view model, then every view model that extends it can subscribe to it internally.

Comment: i currently have 1 Context class that acts as the center of communication. Though this is based on static methods, and am not a fan of it...  In your explanation, how do the 2 instances communicate with each other, since they are initiated seperately?